# Get Title from Crystal Report in C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am trying to extract the title from a Crystal report with c#.  I am having trouble locating the code to find this title.  Here is a picture on the CR designer interface.

[image: Crystal Reports Document Properties]

I am basically trying to find the .net equivalent of CRAXDRT.Report.ReportTitle which is what is currently working in MS-Access VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle
```

Here is the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664938(v=vs.71).aspx